# is it possible to remove zip/postal code field in magento

Tags: magento

is it possible to remove zip/postal code field depending on country chosen in the address section of the checkout page in Magento?

e.g. when a user chooses 'Ireland' the field disappears on the fly.

thanks
Dave

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9418237/693207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme (don't modify the existing themes), copy `js/opcheckout.js` and modify that.

Add your observer to the zipcode fields. The best is to hide the zipcode, as the client-side validation won't fire then.

If you would like some code to get you started, I can post that in an edit.

Answer (score 3):

In the admin panel there is an option to make zip code optional for specific countries:

*System-> Configuration -> General -> Countries Options -> "Postal Code is Optional for the following countries"*

Select your specific countries which you want to make optional.

If this isn't enough with a some basic modification you should be able to make the field invisible as well.

Comment: This setting makes the field appear as not require, when the address is submitted, it still validates the postcode.

Answer (score 0):

Magento hasn't anything built-in yet. You have to wrote some javascript to do that and, of course, control this flow into Magento Core classes.

Answer (score 0):

on Magento 1.7.0.2

first you have to remove 'required-entry' on zipcode field (you can use jquery to remove class)

then

go to Mage_Checkout_OnepageController

on saveBillingAction() method

```
$result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

$result = array() // clear error message;
```

and then on saveShippingAction() method

```
$result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

$result = array() // clear error message;
```

hope works!!